# AngularJs Reset Dropdown boxes on form

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an application using angular. Most of my forms utilize Dropdown boxes. The first time the form loads all of the selects have their default values, but if I load the form again the Dropdown boxes retain the values from the previous load. I've tried calling $setPristine() but this doesn't reset the dropdowns.

How should I go about resetting the dropdowns on each load?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML & angular code?

Comment: Set the value of the dropdown, or it's ng-model to null.

Comment: reset you ng-model and use ng-selected in your html